# Foreign EASA 145 Approval Without NAA Approval

Tags: easa-regulations, cabin, gcaa-uae-regulations

I am just trying to wrap my head around a certain matter.

Can a foreign EASA 145 approved organisation release a component if it is based in a country and does not have that country's NAA's approval?

So for example an EASA 145 Approved AMO based in UAE but without GCAA Approval. It just has the Part 145 EASA approval but does not have GCAA CAR 145 approval

Is there any reason why it is allowed or not allowed (Which ever is true).